# Do I have to create a thumb file for each picture?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a website where there's a gallery, in this gallery there are thumbs that when clicked take you to an ad from linkbucks. Then when you wait for 5 secs then you can see the picture in its real size. The problem is, the user can skip this ad by just clicking on the thumb with the right button of the mouse, then select "Show picture" or something like that.
How can I solve this without having to make a thumb image file for each picture?

Note: I need this solution to be in Javascript/Jquery or/and PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you have already served them the full image, they *already have the full image*. Game over.

Make thumbnails.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that you do actually need to create a thumbnail for each image, there’s no way other here.

However, you don’t have to do it manually: PHP is capable of resizing image files, thus generating thumbnails dynamically. Look for tutorials, like [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-dynamically-create-thumbnails/).

Answer (score 2):

You can never stop them unless you make a thumbnail. If a user has javascript disabled they could still download the image. PHP cannot stop them from downloading the image since it is a server side language and must deliver the image to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create thumbnails for images. You can use simple PHP function like bellow.

```
/** 
    * Create new thumb  images using the source image
    *
    * @param  string $source - Image source
    * @param  string $destination - Image destination
    * @param  integer $thumbW - Width for the new image
    * @param  integer $thumbH - Height for the new image
    * @param  string $imageType - Type of the image
    * 
    * @return bool 
    */
    function creatThumbImage($source, $destination, $thumbW, $thumbH, $imageType) 
    {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($source);
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        if ($width*$thumbH>$height*$thumbW) {
            $x = ceil(($width - $height*$thumbW/$thumbH)/2);
            $width = $height*$thumbW/$thumbH;
        } else {
            $y = ceil(($height - $width*$thumbH/$thumbW)/2);
            $height = $width*$thumbH/$thumbW;
        }

        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbW, $thumbH) or die ('Can not use GD');

        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
        }

        if (!@imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbW, $thumbH, $width, $height)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            imagejpeg($newImage, $destination,100);
            imagedestroy($image);
            return true;
        }
    }
```